# Not working when using “whereNotIn” method [laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I filter quantity product but it not working. Please help me
Has product_options
=> where quantity > 0 and parent != null ( ok is child)
=>  where quantity > 0 and parent_id == null ( check product_options  is parent condition not has child )

```
  $products = Product::where($where)->where('products.status', 1)->leftJoin('product_options', 'products.id', '=', 'product_options.product_id')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where(function ($query) {
                        // has option price
                        $query->where(function ($q) {
                            $q->where('product_options.quantity', '>', 0)->whereNotNull('parent_id');
                        })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                            $q->where('product_options.quantity', '>', 0)->whereNotIn('product_options.id', function ($query) {
                                $query->select('parent_id')->from('product_options');
                                 // no working here block
                            });
                        });

                    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
                        //No option
                        $query->where('products.quantity', '>', 0)->whereNotIn('products.id', function ($query) {
                            $query->select('product_id')->from('product_options');
                        });
                    });
                })->select('products.*')->groupBy(['products.id'])->orderBy($orderBy, $order)->paginate($rows);
```

Comment: I believe that you need to do a new query internally. You are using the main `$query` call. You need to do a subselect in your clause and seems that you're adding a new element on main select.

Comment: Dont forget that you can use an array into whereIn-whereNotIn

Comment: What's this part ` $query->select('parent_id')->from('product_options');` supposed to do?

Comment: djunehor I check is parent has child option ?